# how can i disable two days onward on calendar php

Tags: php, html, forms, date, calendar

this is my code, i am able to disable previous date, but how to disable two days onward from the current date

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-calendar"></i></span>
<label for="DateIn">Date IN:</label>
<input type="date" id="in" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="in">
</div>
```

Comment: <?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('-2 day')); ?>

Comment: Thank you, i able to disable it. just changed a bit from your code <?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+2 day')); ?>

Comment: i think in that case you need to use max="" check the doc,